# how to check dynamically created radiobutton in Form_Load Event

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have created radio button dynamically by giving the email as text but I am not getting how to set last selected radio button on form load.
Means when i last checked radiobutton show on form_load
Actually i am getting Text and Name but in form load i unable to checked

plz help me

```
For Each c As Control In dynamictablelayout.Controls
        If c.GetType Is GetType(RadioButton) Then
            Dim rb As RadioButton = DirectCast(c, RadioButton)
            If rb.Checked Then
                selectedmailID = rb.Text
                rb.Select()
                If Me.dynamictablelayout.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)().Any(Function() rb.Checked) Then
                    'One of the RadioButton controls in TableLayoutPanel1 is checked.
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: you want to set values in 1 life cycle of app or you want that value back after form close and open?

Comment: A bit off topic: I see you tagged your question with C# and VB.NET, but it seems that you are focusing around VB.NET. May I ask what your plan will be with C#? Or did you mean this so that either VB.NET and C# examples / ansers are welcome?

Comment: You can create a List of CheckedItem class and store it into My.Settings. But, First you have to create a setting from Project Property->Settings tab. Then you can retrieve and save all selected radio button items in that list.

Comment: @RvdV79 we can do in any language not a problem ans are welcome

Comment: @Tithi Patel, Can you explain more with small example ?

Comment: Dynamically added controls doesnt persist viewstate, if control values are getting lost on postback its viewstate of dynamic controls causing issue